# Rcpp omp_set_num_threads within a package

Tags: c++, rcpp

I wrote the following simple example with Rcpp and OpenMP that works fine when I source the cpp file from RStudio:

```r
#include <Rcpp.h>
#include <omp.h>

// [[Rcpp::plugins(openmp)]]

using namespace Rcpp;

// [[Rcpp::export]]
NumericMatrix my_matrix(int I, int J, int nthreads) {
  NumericMatrix A(I,J);
  int i,j,tid;
  omp_set_num_threads(nthreads);
#pragma omp parallel for private(i, j, tid)
  for(int i = 0; i < I; i++) {
    for(int j = 0; j < J; j++) {
      tid = omp_get_thread_num();
      A(i,j) = tid ;
    }
  }

  return A;
}


/*** R
set.seed(42)
  my_matrix(10,10,5)
*/
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10]
 [1,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0
 [2,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0
 [3,]    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1     1
 [4,]    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1     1
 [5,]    2    2    2    2    2    2    2    2    2     2
 [6,]    2    2    2    2    2    2    2    2    2     2
 [7,]    3    3    3    3    3    3    3    3    3     3
 [8,]    3    3    3    3    3    3    3    3    3     3
 [9,]    4    4    4    4    4    4    4    4    4     4
[10,]    4    4    4    4    4    4    4    4    4     4
```

However, the same code does not work as expected if I create a package:

```r
> rcpphello::my_matrix(10,10,5)
      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10]
 [1,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0
 [2,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0
 [3,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0
 [4,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0
 [5,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0
 [6,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0
 [7,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0
 [8,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0
 [9,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0
[10,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0
```

Why is the same code only using one thread if I call it from within my package? In case it helps, I pushed all the code to [this github repo](https://github.com/ignacio82/rcpphello)

Comment: From the top of my head, standard OpenMP environment variable settings govern that. And, of course, the helper package [RhpcBLASctl](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RhpcBLASctl/index.html).  Oh, I see you have the call.  So then @coatless is entirely correct.

Comment: Two caveats: Don't use data structures from `Rcpp` for parallel processing. the ones from `RcppParallel` can be used, though. R uses column major layout for matrices. Generally it is best to follow that in your code.

Comment: @ralf-stubner could you show me the answer you have in mind with `RcppParallel`? I just started to learn this stuff and it would be great to see your answer implemented.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add to `src/Makevars` and `src/Makevars.win`:

```
PKG_CXXFLAGS = $(SHLIB_OPENMP_CXXFLAGS)
PKG_LIBS = $(SHLIB_OPENMP_CXXFLAGS)
```

This enables the `-fopenmp` flag. Otherwise, you will not end up having OpenMP enabled in your package.

**Note:** When using:

```
// [[Rcpp::plugins(openmp)]]
```

This sets the `-fopenmp` parameter *only* when run with `sourceCpp()`. This option does **not** transfer into a package. Hence, we must establish the setting in `Makevars` and `Makevars.win`.

A short example can be found here:

https://github.com/r-pkg-examples/rcpp-and-openmp

Though, I'll need to clean it up a bit.

Answer (score 1):

@coatless answered the question already. I would like to add one caveat: Don't use data structures from R or Rcpp within parallel code. You can use [RcppParallel](https://rcppcore.github.io/RcppParallel/), though:

```
#include <Rcpp.h>
// [[Rcpp::plugins(openmp)]]
#include <omp.h>

// [[Rcpp::depends(RcppParallel)]]
#include <RcppParallel.h>

using namespace Rcpp;

// [[Rcpp::export]]
NumericMatrix my_matrix(int I, int J, int nthreads) {
  NumericMatrix A(I,J);
  // create a thread safe accessor for A
  RcppParallel::RMatrix<double> a(A);
  int tid;
  omp_set_num_threads(nthreads);
#pragma omp parallel for private(tid)
  for(int j = 0; j < J; j++) {
    for(int i = 0; i < I; i++) {
      tid = omp_get_thread_num();
      a(i, j) = tid ;
    }
  }

  return A;
}


/*** R
set.seed(42)
my_matrix(12,10,5)
*/
```

Note that I have also changed the access to column major and removed the additional declaration of `i` and `j`. Note that variables declared inside of a `parallel` section are automatically private.

And in case you want to use R's RNG (since you are setting the seed), there is another "don't do that". Have a look at packages like [sitmo](https://cran.r-project.org/package=sitmo) or [dqrng](https://cran.r-project.org/package=dqrng) for RNGs that can be used with parallel code.

Comment: Thanks a lot @ralf-stubner. Could you explain what the line `RcppParallel::RMatrix<double> a(A);` is doing and why do you do `a(j, i)` if the function declares `NumericMatrix A(I,J);`? If i call `my_matrix(12,10,5)` using your code R crashes

Comment: @Ignacio That line creates a thread safe accessor for `A`. See the linked RcppParallel documentation for more. Thanks for check with non-square matrices. That was indeed to simple minded. The switch to column major access is now fixed.